# error: overloaded method value createDataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

I tried to create Apache Spark dataframe

```
val valuesCol = Seq(("Male","2019-09-06"),("Female","2019-09-06"),("Male","2019-09-07"))
valuesCol: Seq[(String, String)] = List((Male,2019-09-06), (Female,2019-09-06), (Male,2019-09-07))
```

Schema

```
val someSchema = List(StructField("sex", StringType, true),StructField("date", DateType, true))
someSchema: List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField] = List(StructField(sex,StringType,true), StructField(date,DateType,true))
```

It does not work

```
val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(valuesCol),StructType(someSchema))
```

I got error

```
<console>:30: error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  (data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)], org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
       val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(valuesCol),StructType(someSchema))
```

Should I change date formatting in valuesCol? What actually causes this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `import spark.implicits._` you could convert `Seq` into `Dataframe` in place

```
val df: DataFrame = Seq(("Male","2019-09-06"),("Female","2019-09-06"),("Male","2019-09-07"))
    .toDF() // <--- Here
```

Explicitly setting column names:

```
val df: DataFrame = Seq(("Male","2019-09-06"),("Female","2019-09-06"),("Male","2019-09-07"))
    .toDF("sex", "date")
```

For the desired schema, you could either cast column or use a different type

```
//Cast
Seq(("Male","2019-09-06"),("Female","2019-09-06"),("Male","2019-09-07"))
  .toDF("sex", "date")
  .select($"sex", $"date".cast(DateType))
  .printSchema()

//Types
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
Seq(
  ("Male",   new java.sql.Date(format.parse("2019-09-06").getTime)),
  ("Female", new java.sql.Date(format.parse("2019-09-06").getTime)),
  ("Male",   new java.sql.Date(format.parse("2019-09-07").getTime)))
  .toDF("sex", "date")
  .printSchema()

//Output
root
 |-- sex: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
```

Regarding your question, your `rdd` type is known, `Spark` will create schema accordingly to it.

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, String)] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(valuesCol)
spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I got error: not found: type DataFrame,Using Scala version 2.11.12. How to fix dependancies?

Comment: Solved with proper import.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your `valuesCol` as `Seq` of `Row` instead of `Seq` of `Tuple` :

```
 val valuesCol = Seq(
    Row("Male", "2019-09-06"),
    Row ("Female", "2019-09-06"),
    Row("Male", "2019-09-07"))
```